# how to replace two things at once with sed?

Tags: shell, sed

Given is string: `dog apple orange banana`

I need to make it: `monkey apple cow banana`

That is without calling sed twice.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The following sed example should solve your problem. sed allows multiple -e switches, which allows you to replace more than one thing at a time.

```
sed -e 's/dog/monkey/g' -e 's/orange/cow/g'
```

Comment: Imho more readable, opposing to  user123444555621 answer.

Answer (score 60):

Use `;` to queue commands:

```
sed -e 's/dog/monkey/g;s/orange/cow/g'
```

Comment: Would you provide a demonstration as to how this works? I could not get it to work having put dog apple orange banana into a file test.txt. Isn't ; for separating bash commands?

Comment: This should work: `sed -e 's/dog/monkey/g;s/orange/cow/g'
 files.txt`. Make sure to quote the sed script, so that bash does not eat up the semicolon.

Comment: @user123444555621 Does it replace in file without `-i` option? You can add your comment in answer, because it is good comment.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using capture groups, such as `\(.*\)`, which are formed with parentheses, and back references, such as `\1`, `\2`, etc. that reference each capture group.

```
sed 's|dog\(.*\)orange\(.*\)|monkey\1cow\2|'
```