# Replace word in string if found in dictionary efficiently

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings, and a dictionary of words and their replacement:

```
titles = ['The cat in the hat', 'Horton hears a who', \ 
          'Green eggs and ham', 'The butter battle book', 'My book about me']
wlist = {'cat': 'word1', 'hat': 'word2', 'Horton': 'word3', \
         'eggs': 'word4', 'butter': 'word5', 'book': 'word6'}
```

I need to replace words present as keys in the dictionary with their corresponding values, if found in the string. 
I have the following code so far:

```
for i, book in enumerate(titles):
     for k,v in wlist.items():
         if k in book:
             book = book.replace(k, v)
             titles[i] = book
```

Which gives me the output:

```
['The word1 in the word2',
 'word3 hears a who',
 'Green word4 and ham',
 'The word5 battle word6',
 'My word6 about me']
```

Is there a more efficient (faster) way to do this, maybe without the two for loops? The list I actually have is quite big!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas (and my rationales for them). Please measure them on your data!

The big ideas are to reduce the Python code in favor of C-implemented Python functions and to combine data with sentinels to get help from your cache.

The first idea is to combine all the strings into one, separated by some kind of sentinel value not found in the strings, do the substitution, and them separate them again. I think this might be faster because strings are immutable so Python won't keep reallocating them when the substitution occurs (though I'm sure it keeps some sort of cache, you might be re-using it), you might benefit from any algorithmic advantages `.replace` might give you over the one string, and you're only traversing one string, so you might get a cache speedup. Of course, you'll have to pay the cost of combining and separating all the strings and making sure your sentinel isn't in the data.

The second idea (stolen from [this article](https://emilics.com/notebook/enblog/p869.html) ) is to use a regex to replace the strings, so the regex library only has to traverse the string once using whatever C-implemented magic it uses.

So, combining those two ideas:

```
import re

# I'm using '\n' to join the strings. Of course, if you can control your input,
# you can just load the list into this format instead of converting it
titles = '\n'.join(['The cat in the hat', 'Horton hears a who', \
          'Green eggs and ham', 'The butter battle book', 'My book about me'])

wlist = {'cat': 'word1', 'hat': 'word2', 'Horton': 'word3', \
         'eggs': 'word4', 'butter': 'word5', 'book': 'word6'}

robj = re.compile('|'.join(wlist.keys()))
result = robj.sub(lambda m: wlist[m.group(0)], titles)
result = result.split('\n') # uncombine
print(result)
```

Once again, this is effectively guesswork. One or both or none of these ideas might help, or I could be completely out of left field. Once you test them, I'd love to see numbers!

Comment: If you aren't committed to using Python, you might be able to use a specialized tool like sed to get the speed you need:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565877/how-to-replace-two-things-at-once-with-sed

Comment: @AnnaR, Did you get any numbers?